# How can I call the defined function?

Tags: python, camera, kivy

I write the code as the following, it reports me the name error. I don't know why. I haved defined the on_mouse before I call it.

```
def on_mouse(event,x,y,flags,params):
    global img,point1,point2
    img2 =img.copy()
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        point1 = (x,y)
        cv2.circle(img2,point1,10,(0,255,0),5)
        cv2.imshow('image',img2)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and (flags & cv2.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON):
        cv2.rectangle(img2,point1,(x,y),(255,0,0),5)
        cv2.imshow('image',img2)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        point2 = (x,y)
        cv2.rectangle(img2,point1,point2,(0,0,255),5)
        cv2.imshow('image',img2)
        min_x = min(point1[0],point2[0])
        min_y = min(point1[1],point2[1])
        width = abs(point1[0]-point2[0])
        height = abs(point1[1]-point2[1])
        cut_img = img[min_y:min_y+height,min_x:min_x+width]
        cv2.imwrite('new.jpg',cut_img)

def take_image(self):
    Clock.unschedule(self.update)
    file_path = self.camera.capture(gp.GP_CAPTURE_IMAGE)
    camera_file = self.camera.file_get(file_path.folder, file_path.name, gp.GP_FILE_TYPE_NORMAL)
    ...
    cv2.imwrite(capture_path,image)
    cv2.namedWindow('img')
    cv2.setMouseCallback('img',on_mouse)
    cv2.imshow('img',image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I am sure the image has stored in capture_path. but when I want to call the on_mouse function, it reports the error.
The detail error message is as blow:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Trackback (most recent call last):
    File"/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py" line 954, in _bootstrap_inner self.run()
    File"/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py" line 892, in run self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    File "/home/user002/app.py", line 220, in capture App.camera.take_image()
    File "/home/user002/cameraControll.py", line 189, in take_image cv2.setMouseCallback('img', on_mouse)
    NameError:name 'on_mouse' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

change the take_image(self) to
def take_image(on_mouse_callback):

this should solve it tell me if not

Comment: it reports error, NameError: name 'self' is not defined.

Comment: my bad, maybe it is solved if you add both, self and mouse callback?

Comment: Yes, I did it before, I changed to def take_image(self, on_mouse_callback), then when I called the take_image function in another py file, I write App.camera.take_image(self, on_mouse_callback), but it report the error: App.camera.take_image(self, on_mouse_callback) NameError: name'on_mouse_callback' is not defined

Comment: I will try this myself this evening, I hope thats okay for you (ca. 4pm GMT+1)

Comment: Thanks Karo. I solved this problem with my friend.  Changed the code to cv2.setMouseCallback('img',self.on_mouse), the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Update the code:

```
def on_mouse(self,event,x,y,flags,params):
    global img,point1,point2
    img2 =img.copy()
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        point1 = (x,y)
        cv2.circle(img2,point1,10,(0,255,0),5)
        cv2.imshow('image',img2)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and (flags & cv2.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON):
        cv2.rectangle(img2,point1,(x,y),(255,0,0),5)
        cv2.imshow('image',img2)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        point2 = (x,y)
        cv2.rectangle(img2,point1,point2,(0,0,255),5)
        cv2.imshow('image',img2)
        min_x = min(point1[0],point2[0])
        min_y = min(point1[1],point2[1])
        width = abs(point1[0]-point2[0])
        height = abs(point1[1]-point2[1])
        cut_img = img[min_y:min_y+height,min_x:min_x+width]
        cv2.imwrite('new.jpg',cut_img)

def take_image(self):
    Clock.unschedule(self.update)
    file_path = self.camera.capture(gp.GP_CAPTURE_IMAGE)
    camera_file = self.camera.file_get(file_path.folder, file_path.name, gp.GP_FILE_TYPE_NORMAL)
    ...
    cv2.imwrite(capture_path,image)
    cv2.namedWindow('img')
    cv2.setMouseCallback('img',self.on_mouse)
    cv2.imshow('img',self.image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```